# SQLite add blank 'alias' column to query

Tags: sqlite

Using SQLite in VB.net project I had an SQL string that created (added) new columns on the fly when a data table was populated.

```
SQLString = "Select Column1, Column2, Null as 'NewColumn', column4 from Table
```

the above worked (for last 3 years) and allowed me to add temporary columns to a table without changing the Database structure. This was until SQLite DLL version 1.0.95.0. The above now causes the schema to be missing the key column which is column1. That is, the data is there but the table is not 
recognized as having a key column. Using alias columns still works, I can have

```
 SQLString = "Select Column1, Column2, Column2 as 'NewColumn', column4 from Table
```

however Other then using a 'dedicated' Blank Column in the database to act as fillers for the newcolumn/s is there a way to do this?

Further info:
I use SQLite coded in VB.net using the System.Data.SQLite.dll. I have used this process from version 1.0.81.0 to 1.0.94.0

I downloaded the System.Data.SQLite (1.0.95.0) version yesterday from SQLite website. Upon implementation of this DLL my program fails, with error “Table doesn't have a Primary Key” when try working with a particular table. When I revert to 1.0.94.0 DLL there is no issue and the program works as expected and as it has been these last 3 years using the different versions outlined above.

Nothing else is changed other then the program references the different version of the DLL. I can go back and forth; from 94 to 95 = Fail. Back from 95 to 94 = OK.

The table does have a Primary Key. The data IS being filled into the table and has correct schema types. However when I try finding a row on the table I get the error message.

Dim findrow As DataRow = InfoRows.Rows.Find("Sample1") crashes with the error.

The real sample is a very complicated table and Query however I can reproduce the error simply with the SQL string above, take out the "Null as 'NewColumn'" and there is no error.

Comment: I cannot try this and I have no idea if it is related, but does it make a difference if you [cast](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr) `NULL` to explicitely assign a data type?

Comment: If I understand correctly; something like "SQLString = "Select Column1, Column2, Cast(Null as NewColumn), column4 from Table" ? I tried it and it does not work. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: I meant something like `... CAST(NULL AS INTEGER) AS NewColumn ...`. Also, what happens if you select `Column1` twice with different aliases or move it to the end of the column list of your query?

Comment: The cast did not work. Using the Column1 as 2 different aliases works. That is what I tried to avoid as it means I have to have a Spare column in the database to reference. Which would not be so bad if changing database structure was not such a pain in SQLite. The spare Blank column approach is the last  resort. One would think that any or just one of the general SQL methods would work. Things like  'None' AS NewCol, 0 AS NEWCol, NULL AS NewCol, '' AS NewCol

Comment: The query looks fine. Casting NULL won't do anything, as SQLite has manifest typing. What is your schema and what is the error message? Also the current version of SQLite is 3.8.8.3; I suspect that the "SQLite DLL version" is the version of the _bindings_ to SQLite.

Comment: Iam editing the message to include the error message and actual codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted the problem to SQLite as a bug. It didn't take very long at all, and the correspondence I have exchanged states that the problem will be resolved in the next release. Excellent service from SQLite! Thank You.

EDIT:
The issue is now fixed with the System.Data.SQLite.DLL version 1.0.96.0 available for download!

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/info/92dbf1229a) in 1.0.95.0 that will be [fixed](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/info/154d609bbe) in the next version.